# Patterns between YouTube m. and normal site urls

Tags: url, youtube-api

My site is not able to show uploaded youtube videos when the url is a mobile (m.) site, but it works for the normal youtube site. It seems to me that the mobile and normal urls differ in a pattern, as shown below:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ILbPFSc4_4

http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=5ILbPFSc4_4&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D5ILbPFSc4_4

obviously, the m. is added, as is the /#, and all the &desktop_uri... stuff.

and again:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE

http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=9To-6VIJZRE&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8To-6VIJZRE

What we hope to do is check to see if the url is mobile site, and if it is, parse it so it shows as the normal site.

Does any one know if all youtube urls work this way--if this similar pattern works for all the same videos on mobile and normal sites?

Answer (score 0):

In general, any time you attempt to parse URLs for sites (as opposed to web APIs) by hand, you're leaving yourself open to breakage. There's no "contract" in place that states that a common format will always be used for watch page URLs on the mobile site, or on the desktop site.

The [oEmbed service](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/oembed-support.html) is what you should use whenever you want to take a YouTube watch page URL as input and get information about the underlying video resource as output in a programmatic fashion. That being said, the oEmbed response doesn't include a canonical link to the desktop YouTube watch page, so it's not going to give you exactly what you want in this case. For many use cases, such as when you want to get the embed code for a video given its watch page URL, it's the right choice.

If you do code something by hand, please ensure that your code is deployed somewhere where it would be easy to update if the format of the watch pages ever do change.